# Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, subquery, alias

```
SELECT dept_name,avg_salary
FROM (SELECT dept_name,AVG(salary) AS avg_salary
        FROM instructor
        group by dept_name)
WHERE avg_salary>42000;
```

Comment: Can you describe your problem, provide background information and tell what you have tried to resolve it?

Answer (score 3):

Add the alias to the derived table. For example:

```
SELECT dept_name,avg_salary 
FROM (SELECT dept_name,AVG(salary) AS avg_salary 
      FROM instructor group by dept_name) x
WHERE avg_salary>42000;
```

Do you see the `x` I added?

Answer (score 1):

The Impaler's answer is correct and actually solves the error that you are getting.

Let me pinpoint, however, that you do not need a subquery to achieve your purpose. To filter on an aggregate expression, you can use the `having` clause, which is part of the standard SQL:

```
select dept_name, avg(salary) as avg_salary
from instructor
group by dept_name
having avg(salary) > 42000;
```

On top of that, MySQL extends the standard and lets you use column aliases in the `having` clause, which furthermore simplifies the query:

```
select dept_name, avg(salary) as avg_salary
from instructor
group by dept_name
having avg_salary > 42000;
```

I would expect that this solution should be more efficient than using a subquery (unless the database is smart enough to spot that optimization, in which case it would be equivalent, performance-wise); and it sure is neater and easier to understand.